# PyQt: QGraphicsItemAnimation with setPosAt

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsitem

I got a little problem since I'm unable to create a simple setPos animation by overriding the setPos method like this:

```
def setPos(self, pos):                                                                                                                                                                                          
    print('from %s to %s' % (self.scenePos(), pos))                                                                                                                                                             
    timer = QTimeLine(5000)                                                                                                                                                                                     
    timer.setFrameRange(0, 100)                                                                                                                                                                                 
    animation = QGraphicsItemAnimation()                                                                                                                                                                        
    animation.setItem(self)                                                                                                                                                                                     
    animation.setTimeLine(timer)                                                                                                                                                                                
    x_step = (pos - self.scenePos()).x() / 200                                                                                                                                                                  
    y_step = (pos - self.scenePos()).y() / 200                                                                                                                                                                  
    for i in range(200):                                                                                                                                                                                        
        animation.setPosAt(i/200, self.scenePos() + QPointF(i * x_step, i * y_step))                                                                                                                            
    timer.start()
```

Thanks in advance, b52

Answer (score 1):

@robe: QPropertyAnimation requires the declaring class to be an QObject and I believe QGraphicsItem is not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **QPropertyAnimation**?. With this class you can create animations for any   properties of objects.

```
 QPropertyAnimation * animationPos = new QPropertyAnimation(Object, propertyName);

  animationPos->setDuration(miliseconds);
  animationPos->setStarValue(startValueForProperty);
  animationsPos->setEndValue(endValueForProperty);
```

You should try and you will avoid many conflicts.